# Продвинутый ScrollSpy

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

Приветствую.
Как сделать такой ScrollSpy, как на странице: https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html

Суть заключается в том, что при прокрутке меняется текст в адресной строке. То есть если вы в разделе Color palette, то ссылка будет такой: https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette, если же прокрутите ниже и попадете в раздел Color system, то ссылка будет такой: https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-system и сама ссылка меняется именно при прокрутке.

Как такое реализовать? Простой ScrollSpy с добавлением css классов к элементам нужным при достижении "якорей" или как там я нашел как реализовать и реализовал, но не знаю как сделать это.

```js
var lastId,
  topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
  topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
  menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
  scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) {
      return item;
    }
  });
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;
  var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
      return this;
  });
  cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
  var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
  if (lastId !== id) {
    lastId = id;
    menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("menu__item--current")
      .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("menu__item--current");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <div class="ico gradient1" data-gradient-css="linear-gradient(45deg, #9575cd, #7e57c2, #673ab7, #5e35b1, #512da8, #4527a0, #311b92)"> G </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ripple">
    <div class="overlay-text"> Мой текст </div>
    <br>
    <div class="overlay-href"><a class="overlay-href" href="mailto:xxx@gmail.com" target="_blank">Мой текст 2</a></div>
  </div>
  <script src="mypage/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="mypage/js/ripple.js"></script>
  <div class="menu">
    <nav class="menu menu--ferdinand">
      <ul class="menu__list js-scrollspy-nav" id="top-menu">
        <li class="menu__item menu__item--current">
          <a href="#my-head" class="menu__link">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#my-projects" id="ss2" class="menu__link">Проекты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#my-contacts" class="menu__link">Контакты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu__item">
          <a href="#my-message" class="menu__link">Напишите мне</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте свой код

Comment: Cheg, добавил свой код.